# jQuery error, variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm trying following code to create a plugin. I'm getting error at the line `if(options.controls == true)`

The error I get is '`options is not defined`'.

How should I define it?

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.jwslider = function(options){
        var defaults = {            
            controls: true           
        };      
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);      
    }

    init();

    function init()
    {
        if(options.controls == true)
        {
            alert("controls true");
        }       

    } 

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: `options` is defined only inside the `$.fn.jwslider` scope, you have to declare it outside and then assign it inside that function(you will need to give a new name to the parameter of the function, maybe `opts`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.jwslider = function(options){
        var defaults = {            
            controls: true           
        };      
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);      

        init();

        function init()
        {
            if(options.controls == true)
            {
                alert("controls true");
            }       
        } 
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Then the `options` is accessible inside `init` function

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the `options` variable outside the scope of function.

Currently it is defined in the scope of `$.fn.jwslider` hence it is giving the error.